# How to generate changelog using Doxygen?

Tags: documentation, doxygen, documentation-generation, changelog

I want the newest updates in the documentation generated by Doxygen to be displayed separately on a Change Log page. How can I do this using Doxygen or other scripts?

Comment: I assume you want to have a list of the differences in your code. With doxygen there is no real solution, but I think the best you can o is check the differences between the input for the different versions of your code e.g. by using commands like `diff`

Comment: Write a tool to convert the Change Log into a format Doxygen can read, like Markdown. Add it to the list of auxiliary pages in your document structure.